# Computer starts but not the monitor

Tags: display, power

My friend's computer powers up but monitor does not. The Monitor power button just blinks green light.
I replaced the graphics card, RAM and Hard disk but same happens. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the monitor to another computer to make sure it still works properly? Also have you tried changing the cable to the monitor?

Comment: First try what sbtkd85 suggests, and if it works elsewhere and a new cable doesn't work, your motherboard is probably bad and the computer is not passing POST as a result. It could be something like a bad ram slot, graphics port or something else that can be worked around, so you may need to test out moving some components around, but it does sound like the board.

Comment: @sbtkd85, I've got this computer from friend, monitor is mine, and works with my own desktop computer.

Comment: @MaQleod, I am afraid you are right. I also think that graphics card slot is bad. I have 4 RAM slots, and I will try to put memory in different slots.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Do you get any POST error beeps at boot time? If you do, look them up here: http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm to get a better idea of what might be the issue (hook up speakers if you don't hear anything).

Comment: @KronoS I don't know which operating system is on computer but think that here is hardware problem not software so operating system is not important here.

Comment: If it's win7 you might try win+P which would make it a software issue.  I've had problems sometimes with monitors not being accepted as the 'primary' monitor.

Comment: @sbtkd85, no I don't get any beep.